# Got false notifications

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

I'm quite new to Stack Exchange more particularly Stack Overflow.
Yet with a rep of 6 I got notifications about gaining privileges for up to 20 rep.

I can't use them so there's no real harm in those notifications; the are plain wrong.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information, I'm not exactly sure what you meant? You are saying that they notified you of the privileges that are available at 20 rep even though you don't have these privilege yet?

Comment: My guess: Someone accepted and then unaccepted one of your answers so you were briefly at 21 rep, triggering the notification.

Comment: @yhw42 exactly my guess too, and it's probably on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869054/perlin-noise-image-creation-in-c-sharp/15869290#15869290

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well see [this timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15869054/timeline) of a question where you have [written this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869054/perlin-noise-image-creation-in-c-sharp/15869290#15869290)!

*Here is the important information from the timeline*

```
11:54    unaccepted A   ChronosMOT  
02:11    accepted   A   ChronosMOT
```

You can see the post have been accepted then unaccepted.

That means that for a few hours you gained 15 reputation, which got you at 21. Then when he unaccepted, you went back to 6.

That explains why you received the notifications for having 20+ rep.

Comment: +1 good find on the rep history.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely possibility is that a question-asker briefly accepted one of your answers, bringing your reputation to 21 long enough to trigger the notifications, only to unaccept the answer.

If your reputation goes above one of the privilege thresholds, you will be notified that you gained a privilege; however, if your reputation drops back down below that threshold, you lose the privilege until your reputation once again increases at or above the threshold.

Most likely, your reputation briefly went above 20 reputation.

Note that, while an accept is the likely scenario since it's one action, it is possible two people upvoted one of your posts and then reversed their votes.  Any action that increases your reputation will trigger this notification if you go above the thresholds.